# What is the difference between Start and Left in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I know that `Start = Left` and `End = Rignt` in `ConstraintLayout`.

However, apart from this, what appears on the preview screen was slightly different.

**When constraint is used as `layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"` (and Right)**

[image]

**When constraint is used as `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` (and End)**

[image]

As you can see the difference in the image, when `Left and Right` are used, they are not completely attached to the `parent`, but are slightly apart.
But `Start and End` are attached to `parent`.

Up until this point, I thought they were the same thing.

What is the difference between the two?

*Currently, what I want to do is to attach only the first LinearLayout to the left in the first image. (Leave the positions of the second and third LinearLayout fixed)*

---

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="8dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_set"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/ll_weight"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/set"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/unit_set"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="set"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_weight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/ll_set"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/ll_rep">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/weight"
                android:layout_width="53dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/unit_kg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="lb"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_rep"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/ll_weight"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/rep"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/unit_rep"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="rep"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: What is the id of the view you want to adjust?

Comment: @AliSh I want to attach only the layout of the `id` called `ll_set` to the left.

Comment: "I know that Start = Left and End = Rignt in ConstraintLayout." This is true in English-speaking locales. In Arabic-speaking locales, Start and Left are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are using `app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf` and `app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf`. If you want to change it you should change both of them to `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` and `layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf`.

**You should use one of these combinations(left and right) or (start and end).**

You should not use `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` with `app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf`

Also, when you have to support RTL languages such as Arabic, the start!=left and end!=right

Comment: I agree with this answer. Use all left/right or start/end but don't mix them. Probably better to use left/right and start/end to cover the bases but this may depend upon your minSdk. Anyway, you might consider reporting this as a bug since it is something that the _ConstraintLayout_ team may want to address.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I'm sorry, but I'll ask a little more.

`1.` Why not use `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` and `layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf` together?
(or using End and Left together)

`2.` I want to move only the view with `id` `ll_set to the left`, how can I do it? When using `margin`, `ll_weight` and `ll_rep` also move.

Comment: 1. It is about how ConstarinLayout implemented, 2. You can set layout_width="0dp"  for all linear layouts, if needed add android:gravity for linear layouts too